# Should I continue taking creatine when on a long break from training?

Tags: diet, creatine

I am on a plant-based diet and take 5g of creatine monohydrate every morning to compensate for the lack of its natural consumption. I work out 4-5 days a week, but now I am going on a vacation soon for 8 days, which means that there will be about 10 days without training. Should I be taking creatine during that period to "maintain the load"? Or is it unnecessary?

Comment: Please add what kind of training you are doing?! (lifting, marathon, etc)

Comment: I am doing weighted pull-ups, dips, their variations, and similar exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Creatine is a molecule in an energy system (creatine phosphate) that can rapidly produce energy (ATP) to support cellular function. Thus its performance-enhancing and neuroprotective properties. A well-researched supplement, creatine is remarkably safe for most people.
>
> [examine.com/creatine](https://examine.com/supplements/Creatine/)

Since you have a good understanding of creatine and assuming your diet is unchanged during your holiday, you will have a reduction (possibly to baseline) of water retention.

To get the full effect of taking creatine you should keep taking it during your break as once you get back you will be loaded and ready to utilise its benefits in the gym. Otherwise you will need to wait for your body to build up its level as you either load or take normal dose.

If you don't take creating during your break your levels will drop. As a basic understanding of what creatine is will tell you, you [don't need to cycle creatine](https://examine.com/nutrition/do-you-need-to-cycle-creatine/). And arguably [you do not need to load creatine either](https://examine.com/nutrition/do-i-need-to-load-creatine/).

In terms of muscle mass preservation (understanding that you may retain less water and so cycling off creatine will cause you to lose weight) [A study found no loss in strength or lean tissue mass when you stop taking creatine](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15263100).

**Bottom line,** its up to you. You will probably end up cycling off if you take a break but it wont really impact your life in the marco unless you are aiming to set some PB's straight after your holiday break.

Answer (score 1):

For that short period of time I would not alter your diet.  You body is used to the intake, and I am sure you will do some sort of maintenance style exercising while on vacation

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to stop taking creatine if you are going for 8 days break, your creatine levels in body will decrease if you do so, 
As you are not going to workout I would recommend you taking 5g alternate days, so that levels remain maintained. 
I would have recommended to stop creatine intake if your break was more than 10-15days